# how to use post method in two functions in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two functions which use post method. they are working perfectly. but the problem is I can't use both of the at same time. how can I fix this problem.

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $this->data['result'] = $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
    $this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
}
function genarate_csv(){

    $pro_id = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $this->data['re'] = $this->csv->ExportCSV($pro_id);

}
```

Comment: Clarify what you mean when you say use both at the same time. Also, what happens when you try to use them both at the same time. What is calling these functions?

Comment: when I use both at same time only first one is working and second one is not working

Comment: Use both at the same time as in, somewhere in your code it calls both functions?

Comment: @Goose can you please show me how to do it. because I'm new to codeigniter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buhaaaaa haaaa.... I fixed my problem. I use sessions to solve my problem. I think this will help noobs like me..

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('mymodel');  
    $this->load->model('csv');  
    session_start();
    $this->load->library('session');
}



public function search_keyword($key = "")
   {
       $keyword    =   $this->input->post('keyword');
       $this->data['result']    =   $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
       $_SESSION[$key] = $keyword;            
       $this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
   }

public function download($key = ""){
    //print_r($_SESSION[$key]);

    $keyword = $_SESSION[$key] ;
    //print_r($keyword);
    $this->data = $this->csv->ExportCSV($keyword);
    $this->session->unset_userdata($keyword);
    //$this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
function search_keyword()
    {
        $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
        $this->data['result'] = $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
        $this->data['re'] = $this->genarate_csv($keyword);
        $this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
    }
    function genarate_csv($keyword){
        $re = $this->csv->ExportCSV($keyword);
        return $re
    }
```

Comment: it's not working.then also it runs second function only.

Comment: As in it doesn't display home.html?

Comment: It should work and i am also using this way , please re check

Comment: I double check your code my friend. I run this code it runs first line and second line correctly,  when it comes to line three it jumps to genarate_csv function and give me the csv file. it does not runs line number four in search_keyword.

Comment: would you please use $data instead of $this->data ? Please also check Twig library is loaded or not......

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function search_keyword()
{
    $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
    $this->data['result'] = $this->mymodel->search($keyword);
    $this->data['re'] = $this->csv->ExportCSV($keyword);
    $this->twig->display('home.html', $this->data);
}
```

You can do it in same function

Comment: but I want them as two separate functions. because first I want to display the details and after user click download button I want to generate csv file.

Comment: make that download button ad submit button and add the keyword as hidden field to that form and call second function.

Comment: how can I do it. can you please help me.

Comment: yes I have a separate button for download.actually it is a link "<a href="{{ base_url }}search/genarate_csv">download</a>".

Comment: ok, keep that inside a form with method post, action as your function which generates csv file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88029/discussion-between-niranjan-and-udara-suranga).